# Laravel validation service doesnt work with custom rules

Tags: laravel

I have implemented a Gateway -> Repository pattern and want to integrate validation service with it. I have created the service

https://github.com/octabrain/Laravel4-Patterns/blob/test/app/lib/Sampleapp/ServiceProviders/ValidationServiceProvider.php

Which adds the CustomValidator

https://github.com/octabrain/Laravel4-Patterns/blob/test/app/lib/Sampleapp/Extensions/Validation/CustomValidator.php

This is the actual validation that is getting performed on the user data from the controller

https://github.com/octabrain/Laravel4-Patterns/blob/test/app/lib/Sampleapp/Gateways/UserGateway.php

This are the rules for uservalidator

https://github.com/octabrain/Laravel4-Patterns/blob/test/app/lib/Sampleapp/Services/Validators/UserValidator.php

But the hex validator is never getting called !

I have followed these articles

http://culttt.com/2013/07/29/creating-laravel-4-validation-services/

http://culttt.com/2014/01/20/extending-laravel-4-validator/

Please help.

Edit : Full code is available here : https://github.com/octabrain/Laravel4-Patterns-Full

Comment: Can you provide a "Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example"?  http://sscce.org/

Comment: Uploaded the full code here : https://github.com/octabrain/Laravel4-Patterns-Full

Comment: Solved. Code updated : https://github.com/octabrain/Laravel4-Patterns

Answer (score 1):

It was my mistake, I was not passing anything in the request so the rule was not getting triggered !

Updated the code

See here : https://github.com/octabrain/Laravel4-Patterns